# How to display image on WebGrid Header

Tags: webgrid

I am trying to use the WebGrid in My MVC3 application and in my grid two column Headers i want to display images .So please give some example for this.
By using "format" option i displayed images in column but not in header so please tel me how to acheave this in web grid

Comment: @MvcHtmlString.Create(grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(header: "{Tree}",  format:
            @<text><input class="box"  type="checkbox" /></text>),
        grid.Column("Name")
)).ToString().Replace("{Tree}", "<img src='../Images/MultipleTree.png' alt=''  style='border:none;'/>")).

Comment: that actually works :D

But is there another not so "hacky" solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display multi images, you can use **Html.ActionLink** property in your View as below. In this sample I use Detail/Edit/Delete images as a button under Operation column.

**Note:** Type "Title", "Controller" and "Action" name in Html.ActionLinks according to your project. If you use empty title simply use " ".

```
....
//for using multiple Html.ActionLink in a column using Webgrid
grid.Column("Operations", format: (item) =>
 new HtmlString(
       Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,               
           title = "Detail",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/detail.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink("Edit Record", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID, 
           title = "Edit",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/edit.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink("Delete Record", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,
           title = "Delete",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/delete.png')"
       }, null).ToString()
 )
)
....


<style type="text/css">
    a.icon-link {
        background-color: transparent; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer; 
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        margin-right: 8px; 
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

For my full example, you might look at here: [How to use WebGrid in a cshtml view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042556/how-to-use-webgrid-in-a-cshtml-view)

Regards.